# Quoting words and separating them with commas

Tags: php, function, csv, quotes

The task arose to import a large amount of data into the database. The best option, I considered importing csv. But there was still a problem in the data was not in csv format. I had to write a script myself. The script works fine only if you specify one line, but if you send several data, the script starts to work incorrectly.
It is known that there are lines `123 1234567 Some text`, the task is to bring these data to this kind of `"123","1234567","Some text"`. `“Some text”` - sometimes it doesn’t have a certain size, it sometimes happens in one word, and sometimes it can be 5-6 words.
As I said, the script works fine when I give it only one line per processing, i.e. `$string = '123 1234567 Some text'`, it returns `"123","1234567","Some text"`. But when I give the script more than one line, i.e. `$string = '123 1234567 Some text 321 7654321 Some text more'`, the script returns a slightly different result to me - `"123","1234567","Some text 123","7654321","Some text more"` What am I doing wrong?

````
if (! function_exists("csv_prepare")) {
  function csv_prepare($string) {

    $exp = explode(" ",$string);
    $str = '';
    $k=0;
    foreach ($exp as $key => $value) {

        if( preg_match('/[0-9]{3}/', $value) || preg_match('/[0-9]{7}/', $value) )
        {
          $str .= $value . ',';
        }else{
          $str .= $value . ' ';
        }

    }

    $str = explode(",",$str);
    $finish = '';
    foreach ($str as $key => $value) {
      if($key != array_key_last($str))
      {
        $finish .= '"'.$value.'"'.',';
      }else{
        $finish .= '"'.$value.'"';
      }
    }

    return $finish;

  }
}
//  END csv prepare```
````

Comment: Note that a newline does not count as a space character. So when using `explode()`, the end of a line will be combined with the beginning of the next line, unless there is an explicit space in between.

Maybe first `explode` your input with a newline (careful! Different OSs use different syntaxes!), and then pass each line to your function?

Comment: ```$exp = explode("\n",$string);``` like this?

Comment: In this case, I have to manually transfer each word to a new line, and there are a lot of lines.

Comment: Yes, like this. You don't have to transfer each word, but each line. Also make sure that "\n" is really the supplied newline character(s).

Comment: ```function csv_prepare($string) {
 
 $string = explode("\n\r",$string);
 foreach($string as $key => $value)
 {
  $exp = explode(" ",$value);
 }```

Comment: ```function csv_prepare($string) {
 
 $string = explode("\n\r",$string);
 foreach($string as $key => $value)
 {
  $exp = explode(" ",$value);
 }```
I added such a piece to the script, as a result I got each word into an array, but still the first three digits are skipped from the second iteration.
```Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 1234567
    [2] => Some
    [3]=> Text
    [4]=>321
    [5]=>7654321
    [6]=>Some text yet
}```

```"123","1234567","Some text 321","7654321", "Some text yet 234"...```

Comment: I suspect the problem is somewhere in the condition statement
```foreach ($exp as $key => $value) {  

        if( preg_match('/[0-9]{3}/', $value) || preg_match('/[0-9]{7}/', $value) )  
        {  
          $str .= $value . ',';  
        }else{  
          $str .= $value . ' ';  
        }  

    }```

Comment: Don't replace the function `csv_prepare()`. Instead, use it as an inner function, and use the code you added in the comment as a second separate function.

Comment: Maybe I didn’t quite understand correctly what you meant, but I did like this, the result remained unchanged.  

```$string = explode("\n\r",$string);
 
 foreach($string as $key => $value)
 {
  $f .= csv_prepare($value);
 }
 
echo  csv_prepare($f)  ```

Result:

```""123"",""1234567"",""Some text 321"",""7654321"",""Some text yet 456"",""4567898"",""One text 654"",""8987654"",""Second text " "```

Comment: @noam Not altogether without change, more quotation marks were added :-)